# C# Issue diagnosting InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, recursion, mp3, invalidoperationexception, id3-tag

I am writing a small application to modify ID3-Tags of Audio Files.
The UI is very simple: You choose your media library and can apply various code logic recursively to all files.

I am using TagLib to read and write Tags in my Project.

In order to work with the library, I need to read all Tags and store them in a List of Albums.

The Problem: In the function **private void GenerateClassifiedLibrary(List files)** is an **InvalidOperationException** thrown and I can't find any reason, why this could happen.

Here is the source code of the **main application**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Music_Metadata_Experiments
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Global Variables Declaration
        public static List<Album> classifiedLibrary = new List<Album>();
        // classifiedLibrary is a List of Albums
        // Albums contain Songs
        // Songs contain Tags like "TITLE", "ARTIST", "ALBUM", "GENRE", etc. which can be read and displayed by every Media Player.

        // Start up
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtLibraryPath.Text = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Music";
        }

        private void BtnSelectLibrary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String libraryPath = "";
            List<String> musicFiles;

            if (libraryBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                libraryPath = libraryBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
            }

            if (libraryPath != null && libraryPath != "")
            {
                txtLibraryPath.Text = libraryPath;
                Log("New Library: " + libraryPath);
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Mediathek wird eingelesen. Dieser Vorgang kann je nach Größe sehr lange dauern.\nDrücke Strg+Shift+Esc für mehr technische Infos.\n\nBitte warten!");

            // Reading the Library:
            musicFiles = GetFilesFromLibrary(libraryPath);
            GenerateClassifiedLibrary(musicFiles);
        }

        // Adjustable Code
        private void ExecuteLogic1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { // Not implemented yet
            // Goal: Fix this problem -> Song 1 from DISKNUMBER 1 and Song 1 from DISKNUMBER 2 are shown underneath each other, because DISKNUMBER is missing or corrupted.
            // Function: Finds multiple Songs having TITLENUMBER == 1 but are in the same ALBUM and have the same DISKNUMBER or no DISKNUMBER
            Log("Executing Logic 1");

            Log("Library Count: " + classifiedLibrary.Count);
            foreach (Album album in classifiedLibrary)
            {
                Log("Album: " + album.Name);
            }
        }

        private void ExecuteLogic2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ExecuteLogic3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ExecuteLogic4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ExecuteLogic5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ExecuteLogic6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ExecuteLogic7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ExecuteLogic8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // Helper Methods
        private List<String> GetFilesFromLibrary(string libraryPath)
        {
            String currentFileName = null;
            String fileExtensionToScanFor = "mp3";
            bool skipOnError = true;
            List<String> files = new List<String>();

            try
            {
                foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(libraryPath, "*." + fileExtensionToScanFor, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    currentFileName = file;
                    files.Add(file);
                }
                Log("Found " + files.Count + " Files in Library");
            }
            catch (Exception any)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Erroar reading file: " + currentFileName + " // Problem: " + any.Message);

                if (skipOnError == false)
                {
                    Application.Exit();
                }
            }
            return files;
        }

        private void GenerateClassifiedLibrary(List<String> files)
        {
            Log("Generating a Library to work with");
            TagLib.File currentFile = null;

            foreach (string song in files) // ALL Songs found in Library Folder
            {
                try
                {
                    currentFile = TagLib.File.Create(song);

                    String trackAlbum = currentFile.Tag.Album;

                    // Add at least 1 Album to classifiedLibrary
                    if (classifiedLibrary.Count < 1)
                    {
                        List<TagLib.File> albumTrackList = new List<TagLib.File>();
                        albumTrackList.Add(currentFile);
                        Album firstAlbum = new Album(trackAlbum, albumTrackList);

                        classifiedLibrary.Add(firstAlbum);
                    }

                    // Find an Album in classifiedLibrary to which this track belongs to
                    foreach (Album album in classifiedLibrary) // FIXME: InvalidOperationException thrown HERE
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Album: " + album.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine("Track: " + currentFile.Tag.Title); // not matching to album above

                        if (album.Name == trackAlbum)
                        {
                            // Album found in classifiedLibrary
                            Log("EXISTING Album: " + trackAlbum + " | Track Count = " + album.Tracks.Count);

                            // Now checking if the track exists or add it
                            List<TagLib.File> tracks = album.Tracks;

                            foreach (TagLib.File track in tracks)
                            {
                                if (track == currentFile)
                                {
                                    // Already added to this Album!
                                    Log("Already added: " + track.Tag.Title);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (track.Tag.Album == currentFile.Tag.Album)
                                    {
                                        tracks.Add(track);
                                        Log("X Added Track '" + track.Tag.Title + "' to '" + album.Name + "'.");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        // Next one.
                                    }
                                    // Next one.
                                }
                                // Next one.
                            }
                            album.Tracks = tracks;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Album not found in classifiedLibrary - FIXME: Album existiert und wird trotzdem neu erstellt
                            Log("NEW Album: " + trackAlbum);

                            List<TagLib.File> trackOrigin = new List<TagLib.File>();
                            Album newAlbum = new Album(trackAlbum, trackOrigin);
                            newAlbum.Tracks.Add(currentFile);
                            Log("Y Added Track '" + currentFile.Tag.Title + "' to '" + newAlbum.Name + "'.");

                            classifiedLibrary.Add(newAlbum);

                            Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS 1");
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS 2");
                    } // ------------------------------ Exception
                    Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS 3");
                }
                catch (Exception any)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("GenerateClassifiedLibrary: A more fatal Erroar reading file: " + currentFile.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + any.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");
                }
            }

            // Generating classifiedLibrary done.
            Log("Generated Library Contents: " + classifiedLibrary.Count + " Albums in classifiedLibrary");
        }

        private void Log(String line)
        {
            RtbLogs.Text += "\n" + line;
        }

    }
}
```

Here the source of the **Album** object:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Music_Metadata_Experiments
{
    public class Album
    {
        public String Name
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public List<TagLib.File> Tracks
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public Album(String name, List<TagLib.File> tracks)
        {
            Name = name;
            Tracks = tracks;
        }

        public bool Contains(String trackTitle)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (TagLib.File track in Tracks)
                {
                    if (track.Tag.Title == trackTitle)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Exception occured while checking Album.Contains(" + trackTitle + ")");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Example of the **Console Output**:

```
Album: Holz (Weihnachtslied) - Single
Track: Curse My Name
SUCCESS 1
SUCCESS 2
Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.InvalidOperationException" in mscorlib.dll
------------------------------------------
GenerateClassifiedLibrary: A more fatal Erroar reading file: C:\Users\XXX\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Music\Blind Guardian\At the Edge of Time\1-05 Curse My Name.mp3
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Die Sammlung wurde geändert. Der Enumerationsvorgang kann möglicherweise nicht ausgeführt werden.
   bei System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   bei Music_Metadata_Experiments.Form1.GenerateClassifiedLibrary(List`1 files) in C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Projekte\Music Metadata Experiments\Music Metadata Experiments\Form1.cs:Zeile 152.
------------------------------------------
```

[A Screenshot of what's happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoFYz.png)

Btw: I am new to C#

--

Edit: It's now working as expected.
I've also set the Application to x64 to enable the Processing of larger Music Libraries.

Updated Project: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AphAKlhyqhP4g2eEk-3aqLeifo89?e=ACkb6w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there error is key here:
`Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Die Sammlung wurde geändert. Der Enumerationsvorgang kann möglicherweise nicht ausgeführt werden.`

In English roughly translates to the following error message:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute`

This means you are looping through a list, but you are modifying that list (e.g. adding or removing items) while you are looping through it.

**Sample:**

```
var lines = new List<string>();
lines.Add("hello");
lines.Add("world");
foreach(var line in lines) 
{
    lines.Add("adding a new item"); // Invalid operation
}
```

It's an invalid operation to add / remove an item from the list while you are looping through it.

In your case this is the culprit:

```
classifiedLibrary.Add(newAlbum); // << This is not valid inside a loop.
Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS 1");
```

How to fix this? Simple - create an extra list that you add items to when they match a certain criteria, and don't use the list you are currently looping through.

**Other tip:**

I strongly advise to set your windows language to english. This will help you (as there are far more resources available on stackoverflow with the right english translation).

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, that was easier than I thought.

Comment: You are welcome @LordofProductivity. When my answer helped you fix your problem please let everyone know by selecting my 'answer' as the accepted answer. This way everyone on SO will know that this question was answered.

Answer (score 1):

`InvalidOperation` appears to be coming because you are trying to modify `classifiedLibrary` within the `foreach` loop. Try to update your `foreach` lookup code as below:

```
// using System.Linq;

foreach (Album album in classifiedLibrary.ToList())
```

This way you would be enumerating a copy of `classifiedLibrary` collection (and not `classifiedLibrary` itself) which would allow you to add an item to `classifiedLibrary` within the loop.

Comment: Ok, but how do I iterate over classifiedLibrary and in the next iteration include the one more item I need to check? I guess I'll rewrite this function, but the Exception is gone.

Comment: Not sure if I got your question, using `ToList` you would be iterating a *copy* `classifiedLibrary`. This way you can add the `newAlbum` to `classifiedLibrary` same way you are doing it now.

Comment: You're right, I don't need to have the new Album available in the next iteration, because there's a loop around it to add each individual Track. Thank you.

Comment: I've used .ToArray, because .ToList was not suggested, but it worked fine.